# Weblogic JMS System Error

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, jmstemplate

We're getting a JMS error which we don't have a lot to go with:

> org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException:
>   Uncategorized exception occured during
>   JMS processing; nested exception is
>   **weblogic.jms.common.JMSException:[JMSClientExceptions:055039]** A system
>   error has occurred. The error is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   com.mywebsite.SendMessageSync(ProducerServices.java:131)
>
> ```
>     at com.mywebsite.SendMessageSync(ProducerServices.java:115)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.Producer.sendMessage(FormsCRRProducer.java:56)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.Producer.useNewGetTemplateData(GenerateFormsManagerBean.java:522)                      
>
>     at com.mywebsite.Producer.GenerateFormsManagerBean.doService(GenerateFormsManagerBean.java:114)                                  
>
>     at com.mywebsite.Producer.doServiceWrapper(AbstractManagerBean.java:175)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.Producer.doServiceRequest(AbstractManagerBean.java:151)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.processcontainer.AbstractServlet.doManagerBeanServiceAndPresentation(AbstractServlet.java:1911)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.processunit.servlet.CportalParamServlet.doService(CportalParamServlet.java:107)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.fw.processcontainer.AbstractServlet.service(AbstractServlet.java:983)
>
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.processunit.filter.UploadMultipartFilter.doFilter(UploadMultipartFilter.java:28)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3229)
>
>     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>
>     at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2002)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1908)
>
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1362)
>
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
>
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
> ```

The only lead I have is line **127** in the code which is indicated by this error:

> Caused by:
>   weblogic.jms.common.JMSException:
>   [JMSClientExceptions:055039]A system
>   error has occurred. The error is
>   java.lang.Nul lPointerException
>
> ```
>     at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.handleException(JMSSession.java:2853)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConsumer.receive(JMSConsumer.java:629)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConsumer.receive(JMSConsumer.java:488)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.client.WLConsumerImpl.receive(WLConsumerImpl.java:155)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:734)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:706)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$9.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:681)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:447)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:679)
>
>     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelectedAndConvert(JmsTemplate.java:784)
>
>     at com.mywebsite.jms.service.ProducerServices.SendMessageSync(ProducerServices.java:127)
>
>     ... 25 more
> ```

This is line 127:

```
try {
    Thread.yield();
    //line 127 below
    status=(StatusMessageBean)getJmsTemplate.receiveSelectedAndConvert(statusDestination, "JMSCorrelationID='"+ producerMsg.getProcessID() +"'");
    Thread.yield();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Thread.yield();
    loggingInterface.doErrorLogging(e.fillInStackTrace());          
}
```

According to the [BEA documentation,](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e14397/JMSClientException.html) we should contact BEA about error 055039 but I would like to try asking here first before bringing this to them?

Some more errors:

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
>     at weblogic.jms.common.JMSVariableBinder$JMSCorrelationIDVariable.get(JMSVariableBinder.java:127)
>
>     at weblogic.utils.expressions.Expression.evaluateExpr(Expression.java:271)
>
>     at weblogic.utils.expressions.Expression.evaluateExpr(Expression.java:298)
>
>     at weblogic.utils.expressions.Expression.evaluateBoolean(Expression.java:209)
>
>     at weblogic.utils.expressions.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:167)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.common.JMSSQLFilter$Exp.evaluate(JMSSQLFilter.java:304)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.common.SQLFilter.match(SQLFilter.java:158)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.MessageList.findNextVisible(MessageList.java:274)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.nextFromIteratorOrGroup(QueueImpl.java:441)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.nextMatchFromIteratorOrGroup(QueueImpl.java:350)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.get(QueueImpl.java:233)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.addReader(QueueImpl.java:1069)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.ReceiveRequestImpl.start(ReceiveRequestImpl.java:178)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.ReceiveRequestImpl.<init>(ReceiveRequestImpl.java:86)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.kernel.internal.QueueImpl.receive(QueueImpl.java:820)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.backend.BEConsumerImpl.blockingReceiveStart(BEConsumerImpl.java:1172)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.backend.BEConsumerImpl.receive(BEConsumerImpl.java:1383)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.backend.BEConsumerImpl.invoke(BEConsumerImpl.java:1088)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:759)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsyncInternal(DispatcherImpl.java:129)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsync(DispatcherImpl.java:112)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:1046)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:72)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEConsumer.receive(FEConsumer.java:557)
>
>     at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEConsumer.invoke(FEConsumer.java:806)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:759)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.invoke(DispatcherServerRef.java:276)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.handleRequest(DispatcherServerRef.java:141)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.access$000(DispatcherServerRef.java:36)
>
>     at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef$2.run(DispatcherServerRef.java:112)
>
>     ... 2 more
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first step would be to figure out exactly which reference was null. Can you dump out each variable used in line 127 before you execute line 127 itself?

Comment: Hi there. That's what I was thinking as well but this error isn't easy to replicate :(